# Bash shell using AWK to add up several respective columns / fields?

Tags: bash, awk

Wondering if someone could point me in right direction using bash shell scripting and awk to add up several column/fields and print out a summary.

I want to take stats outputted in the following format

```
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 1.0, TOT_REQS: 2,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 10
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 2.0, TOT_REQS: 0,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 20
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 3.0, TOT_REQS: 2,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 30
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 4.0, TOT_REQS: 1,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 40
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 5.0, TOT_REQS: 0,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 50
```

and total them up for one line output like

```
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 15.0, TOT_REQS: 5,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 2.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 150
```

thanks

Comment: Do you require awk? This can be done in perl too -- and in python, and many other scripting languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is really easy to use.

```
$ awk '/REQ_PROCESSING/{x+=$3; y+=$5; z+=$7}; END{print x, y, z}' input.txt
0 15 5
```

I think you can do the rest. Happy coding!

Comment: thanks Jaypal and kev, your examples definitely helped me understand what to do. Looks like kev's example much simplier to use and just what I need :)

Comment: It is simpler but you will have to run it twice for calculating all 5 statistics. My answer was based on your desired output. The scary part of my code is the formatting. But as long as it gets you on your way, thats good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you -

**Your File:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 1.0, TOT_REQS: 2,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 10
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 2.0, TOT_REQS: 0,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 20
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 3.0, TOT_REQS: 2,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 30
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 4.0, TOT_REQS: 1,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 40
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0, REQ_PER_SEC: 5.0, TOT_REQS: 0,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 0.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 50
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] sed '{N;s/\n/ /g'} file |  
awk -F"[:,]" '{a=a+$2;b=b+$4;c=c+$6;d=d+$8;e=e+$10} 
END{printf ("%s: %.1f,%s: %.1f,%s: %.1f,\n%s: %.1f,%s: %.1f\n", $1,a,$3,b,$5,c,$7,d,$9,e)}'
REQ_RATE REQ_PROCESSING: 0.0, REQ_PER_SEC: 15.0, TOT_REQS: 5.0,
REQ_RATE CACHE_HITS_PER_SEC: 2.5, TOTAL_CACHE_HITS: 150.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the structure of the data, there are a few conclusions to be drawn:

- `REQ_RATE` carries no information
- The remainder of the lines can be viewed as key-value pairs
- The key-value pairs are separated by commas or by line breaks

So take a two step approach, processing the lines into cleaner key-value pairs:

```
sed -e 's/^REQ_RATE //' -e 's/,[[:space:]]*$//' |
  awk -F ', ' -v OFS='\n' '{ $1=$1; print }'
```

This produces lines with single key-value pairs.

Now pipe the above through another awk stage, summing up the values for each of the keys using an associative array:

```
awk -F ': ' '
  { 
    sum[$1] += $2 
  } 
  END { 
    for (k in sum) { 
      printf("%s: %d, ", k, sum[k]) 
    } 
    printf("\n")
  }'
```

I've done nothing special with the formatting of the output, instead just printing the keys in whatever arbitrary order they are iterated through. Modify the `END` action if you need something more specific.